# How to remove First 6 and last 6 characters from a string using regex or c#

Tags: c#, regex, string, oracle, oracle11g

I am in need of a transformation script that will remove 1st 6 characters and last 6 characters from a string.

String is as follows:
**Email reception@oasisdental.com.au Email**

I need only **reception@oasisdental.com.au**

I am scraping data from the internet and I am getting this Email as a prefix as will as suffix, I want to remove both these Email.
I have tried regex as well as C# but I am not able to make regex or c# code to do this.

Comment: Why would you use regex for this task?

Comment: why regex? string operations will be **MUCH** faster, especially since you know exactly which chars to remove.

Comment: @RohitJain : I would like to use regex as in the transformation script of my software only regex or C# coding is permitted

Comment: @MarcB : Yes I know, but I would like to use regex as in the transformation script of my software only regex or C# coding is permitted. Also I come across several cases where I need to extract data between two words or special characters

Comment: `c# coding`? string operations are part of the string objects in C#...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 var s = "your string";
 s = s.Substring(6,s.Length-12);
```

I think for your requirement, we don't need to care about the number of characters to trim:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"\s.+@.+\s");//This is not a FULL regex for an email address
s = reg.Match(s).Value.Trim();
```

### UPDATE:

```
string upperLetters = new string(Enumerable.Range(65, 26).Select(c => (char)c).ToArray());
Regex reg = new Regex(string.Format("[(]([{0}]{{2}}.+?)[)]", upperLetters));
s = reg.Match(s).Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, There is another case arises today, I have a whole paragraph and I want to extract only that data which is between the parenthesis(parenthesis comes more than once in the paragraph). I want data from those parenthesis which has first two letters in uppercase.

e.g - "Hello buddy, how (are) you doing (NOw a days). Everything is great (isn't) it?"

From the above paragraph I want retreive "NOw a days" data only.
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: @Hemendra why accept the answer which doesn't answer to your new arising problem?

Comment: I am new here, I don't know the rules and all, I have just ticked every one's answer, sorry about that and thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1):

You can also [replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.Replace.aspx) the "Email" string with nothing. However it also remove it from the e-mail name (Ex: bob@email.com)

```
yourStringName.Replace("Email", string.Empty).TrimStart().TrimEnd();
```

You can also use [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx), [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove.aspx) or even a combination of [`TrimStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.TrimStart.aspx) and [`TrimEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.TrimEnd.aspx):

```
string s = s.Substring(6, s.Length - (2 * 6)); //Second parameter is string length, not end index
string s = s.Remove(s.Length - 6, 6).Remove(0, 6);
string s = s.TrimStart("Email ".ToCharArray()).TrimEnd(" Email".ToCharArray());
```

Honestly, there's really a *lot* of ways to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, There is another case arises today, I have a whole paragraph and I want to extract only that data which is between the parenthesis(parenthesis comes more than once in the paragraph). I want data from those parenthesis which has first two letters in uppercase. 

e.g - **"Hello buddy, how (are) you doing (NOw a days). Everything is great (isn't) it?"** 

From the above paragraph I want retreive **"NOw a days"** data only. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

If it really must be regex, use:

```
/\A.{6}|.{6}\Z/
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, There is another case arises today, I have a whole paragraph and I want to extract only that data which is between the parenthesis(parenthesis comes more than once in the paragraph). I want data from those parenthesis which has first two letters in uppercase. 

e.g - **"Hello buddy, how (are) you doing (NOw a days). Everything is great (isn't) it?"** 

From the above paragraph I want retreive **"NOw a days"** data only. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: That would be: /\\(([A-Z]{2}.*?)\\)/

Comment: I am not getting anything with this, output is empty

Comment: How to get everything BUT those first and last 6 chars? Thanks.